# Only receiving MQTT messages in interactive mode within a docker container

Tags: networking, docker, mqtt

I created a micro service (using scala and Akka) that listens to an MQTT broker. As MQTT Library using the paho mqttv3 library.

The service works as expected when running it locally but after packaging it into a docker container, it will only run normally in --interactive (-i) mode. Otherwise, after successful connection to the MQTT broker, it will not receive any messages.

This is a problem, because tools like docker-compose does not support the --interactive flag properly.

My question therefore is:
What does the --interactive (-i) mode change to the network configuration of my docker container? And can this effect be reached in a different way?

**EDIT:**

Currently, to start my docker container, I run the following command:

```
docker run -i --name mqttlistener --net=test_net mqtt-listener:0.3
```

The container will then work as expected (it connects to the MQTT broker and afterwards receives messages).
The same command without `-i` will also start the application and the client will connect to the MQTT broker:

```
[INFO] [02/23/2016 13:34:19.219] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [02/23/2016 13:34:19.347] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://My-Service@mqttlistener:2555]
[INFO] [02/23/2016 13:34:19.349] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://My-Service@mqttlistener:2555]
connecting to mqtt broker: ssl://my.brokers.url:8883
connected
```

But no messages will arrive.
I verified that the process is started with `ps aux`, which will print the running process as expected:

```
daemon   24574  2.7  0.7 7756248 119608 ?      Ssl  14:12   0:02 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /opt/docker/lib/mqttlistener
simon    25729  0.1  0.1 242704 28156 pts/3    Sl+  14:34   0:00 docker run --name mqttlistener --net=test_net
```

Also docker ps looks normal:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b474f0c954dd        mqtt-listener:0.3   "bin/mqttlistener"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       2555/tcp            mqttlistener
```

Also `-p 8883` or `-p 8883:8883` will not change that behavour

**EDIT2:**

`docker events` prints on container start:

```
2016-02-23T15:40:58.664173393+01:00 container create 5c3a7b9b54106735fd2c0c4e7cfd5b6edc210539230a130c2afd9b1b822dad52 (image=mqtt-listener:0.3, name=mqttlistener)
2016-02-23T15:40:58.665446821+01:00 container attach 5c3a7b9b54106735fd2c0c4e7cfd5b6edc210539230a130c2afd9b1b822dad52 (image=mqtt-listener:0.3, name=mqttlistener)
2016-02-23T15:40:59.054709073+01:00 network connect fa703609c50c1a670a450f7d3e2633494fb09bdbdf1a03833344d8af48ad52bb (type=bridge, container=5c3a7b9b54106735fd2c0c4e7cfd5b6edc210539230a130c2afd9b1b822dad52, name=test_net)
2016-02-23T15:40:59.056399012+01:00 container start 5c3a7b9b54106735fd2c0c4e7cfd5b6edc210539230a130c2afd9b1b822dad52 (name=mqttlistener, image=mqtt-listener:0.3)
```

and `docker logs mqttlistener` prints the output that verifies, that the application is started and the connection to the mqtt broker was established:

```
[INFO] [02/23/2016 14:43:27.081] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [02/23/2016 14:43:27.211] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://My-Service@mqttlistener:2555]
[INFO] [02/23/2016 14:43:27.214] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://My-Service@mqttlistener:2555]
connecting to mqtt broker: ssl://my.broker.url:8883
connected
```

When running the container with `-i` the log prints `received: {"sp": {"mi": ...`-messages below that output, which verifies that the mqtt listener works in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things:

- is your application even started inside the docker container in non interactive mode? (you can check even on the host using ps aux)
- is the application port published on the host ?  See the -p option of the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) command.

Once the application is running and the port published, you should connect on the host to the port you exposed.

Comment: The application is started also without the `--interactive` flag. I checked that with `ps aux` and with `docker ps`. I also experimented with the `-p` option (which should not be necessary for the mqtt client). As I said, the exact same configuration works with `--interactive` activated. Without `--interactive`, the application starts, but no messages will arrive

Comment: Can you post `docker events`   and  `docker logs container` to see what is happening

Comment: I added the output of `docker events` and `docker logs` to the question

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem while dockerizing a python3 script using the MQTT broker library.
It's a little late for an answer but anyway if it can help someone:

add the following lines in docker compose :

```
stdin_open: true # docker run -i
tty: true        # docker run -t
```